# Multiple copies of same Angular custom element on same page

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element, angular-elements

I am writing a simple custom element in Angular 13, with the usual wrapping inside another application that uses `createCustomElement` and then `customElements.define` to register it into the browser and creating a single JS bundle.

All is fine until I place 2 copies of the same custom element on the same page.

They same to share everything; for example, a simple `StoreService` is created only once even if the components are two.

Even worse, I am afraid that there would be conflicts with other different custom elements on the same page, say services or nrgx/store, maybe based in on the service name or the store reducer key, I don't know.

Is there a way to completely insulate a custom element written in Angular so that we can be sure it behaves fine whatever the environment it will be used is?

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/autozoom/multiple-elements1

Just run `npm run start:shell`, to go localhost:4200 and open the console.

You will see that the `AppModule` and the `StoreService` are only created once even if the shell's `AppComponent` has 2 copies of the custom element and therefore the service internal state is shared between the 2 copies.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it is a simple custom element, then why don't you write it with native code? If it is because you can't write native code, you are learning Web Components in the wrong order. Learn the Technology first before you apply a Tool (Angular, Lit, etc.).

Comment: it's simple in the repo because this is only a POC, you don't need it complicated to show this issue. I've been using Angular for 5 years now thanks

Answer (score 3):

The "issue" here is how the StoreService is provided.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

providedIn: 'root' means that this Service is, when used, provided **once at the application-level injector**

For more information: https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable

If you want to completely isolate your angular elements, you have the option to provide services at component level.

For this use case, you have to **remove the providedIn property from the @Injectable Decorator** of the service

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService
```

and use the providedIn property in the @Component Decorator of the ShowComponent:

```
  //...
  providers: [StoreService],
})
export class ShowComponent
```

Now everytime the ShowComponent is instantiated, an instance of the StoreService will be provided.

You can verify this by adding a log statement in the constructor of the StoreService, which will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.

Yes, providing it at the component level solves it, but I hoped there was a way to develop the custom element as usual without worrying of what is around.

I mean, that is what custom elements are all about I think, develop and bundle them without having to think where they will be used.

For example, what about ngrx/store?
If I have 2 copies of the same custom element on the same page, they will share the same store, how to avoid it?

I was hoping there was a way to isolate them at a higher level, if this makes sense.
Otherwise, we need to handle tens of special cases that can go wrong when the angular custom element coexists with others, and it's a nightmare.

Comment: So its clear, it is an Angular issue, not a Custom Elements issue

Comment: "custom elements" is a specification, of course it cannot cause any issue :)